# WebApi2 always redirecting first request

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET WebApi2 project hosted on IIS.  Every GET request is redirected to the *same location* as the original request, but the redirect (correctly) strips off the authentication header, so the request fails with a 401.

What's going on?  Why is my initial GET request always redirected?

CURL:

```
    curl https://localhost/myapp/api/test
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController : ApiControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ApiAuthorize]
    [Route("api/test")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ApiAuthorize]
    [Route("api/test")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

IIS Log:

```
   2020-07-31 14:48:32 127.0.0.1 GET /mysite/api/test - 443 - 127.0.0.1 PostmanRuntime/7.26.2 - 302 0 0 13
   2020-07-31 14:48:32 127.0.0.1 GET /MySite/api/test - 443 - 127.0.0.1 PostmanRuntime/7.26.2 https://server/mysite/api/Test 401 0 0 458
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the redirect is triggered by IIS itself.  The original request was to `https://localhost/myapp/api/test` but my application was registered as an application under the default web site as `MyApp`.

It looks like the redirect was IIS correcting the original request to account for the different casing of `myapp`: `https://localhost//MySite/api/Test`

Not sure if this is designed or default behaviour, but it cost me 2 days of debugging :-(

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.